# Trying to use docker with PostgreSQL for a Symfony project with Windows 10 pro

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, symfony

I want to use PostgreSQL in a docker container as my database, but when I want to do a migration in my terminal.

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm php bin/console d:s:u
```

I got an error which is:

> In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 73:
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "database" to address: No address associated with hostname
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "database" to address: No address associated with hostname
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "database" to address: No address associated with hostname

Tried to change my port, the db name but nothing worked... I am on Windows 10 Pro and that works on Ubuntu and Mac OS but not on my operating system.

This is my .env which is used to connect on my db:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://symfony:password@database:5432/symfony?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8
```

Ans this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    nginx:
        build: _docker/nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        volumes:
            - './:/usr/share/nginx/html'
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
    php-fpm:
        build: _docker/php
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - './:/usr/share/nginx/html:consistent'
        depends_on:
            - database
    adminer:
        image: 'adminer:4.7'
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '8081:8080'
        depends_on:
            - database
    composer:
        image: 'composer'
        command: install
        volumes:
            - './:/app'
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
    database:
        image: 'postgres:11.5'
        #        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./_docker/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data:consistent
        ports:
            - '25000:5432'
        environment:
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
            - POSTGRES_DB=symfony
            - POSTGRES_USER=symfony
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: What Symfony version do you use? Also, can you show your db parameters/envvars? Do you use something like `DATABASE_URL=postgresql://symfony:password@database:5432/symfony?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8` or the "old" format?

Comment: Nevermind. I just saw the envvar. Can you ping the `database` container from inside your php-fpm container? Have you tried explicitly [setting up a network in your docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks)?

Comment: Can you include your docker image for php-fpm? The problem may lie in there

Comment: Also, is your database container up and running when you are running the exec?